# JBoss ignoring WEB-INF/lib/*.jar

Tags: spring, hibernate, windows-7, jboss6.x

I'm working on a Spring/Hibernate web app that works fine in Tomcat, but when I go to deploy on JBoss 6.1, I'm having issues where JBoss appears to be ignoring the jars in my WEB-INF/lib folder. I can demonstrate this by removing the common/lib/hibernate-*.jar files and then I will get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceContextType
```

I have all the required hibernate jars in my WEB-INF/lib. I added the -verbose:class flag to see all the classes loaded, and there is no classes being loaded from my war before it parses the web.xml.

I'm mostly wondering if anyone has seen this before and if there are any known reasons why JBoss would ignore the jars. I can post relevant parts of the project if that helps.